# Child job hangs when it is called by two different jobs simultaneously in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two parent jobs which internally call the same child job. 
In the parent job, the child job is being called using the "Trigger/call builds on other projects" option provided by "Parameterized trigger plugin". I checked the "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" checkbox for "Trigger/call builds on other projects" step in the parent job so that the parent job waits till the child job executes completely (either success or failure).

When I fire the two parent jobs simultaneously, the child job never executes. 
The build history of the child job shows two new build numbers with one build showing the message as "pending--Waiting for next available executor" and the other showing "pending". The two builds stay in that state for ever. Even the builds of the parent jobs also keep running for ever.

Please help.

Regards,
Ravi